# Docker tutorial: docker run -it ubuntu ls / gives me a no file/directory error using git bash (Windows)

Tags: docker, git-bash

I'm on the part of the tutorial where it talks about [data persistence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/docker/tutorials/persist-your-data).

First, I run this command to put a random number into a text file within an ubuntu image:

`docker run -d ubuntu bash -c "shuf -i 1-10000 -n 1 -o /data.txt && tail -f /dev/null"`

I think I understand this line pretty well.

Next, the instructions ask me to start a new container (the same image) and I will see that the file is not the same:

`docker run -it ubuntu ls /`

However, when I run the above command, I get the following error:

`/ ls: cannot access 'C:/Program Files/Git/': No such file or directory`

I'm running Windows 10 using Git Bash, and this is being done through VS Code.

For now, I've gotten around this issue by re-running the exact command (docker run -d ubuntu bash -c "shuf -i 1-10000 -n 1 -o /data.txt && tail -f /dev/null"), but I would like to know why the docker run -it ubuntu ls / instructions failed, and what the solution is?

Comment: you will have unexpected behaviors on windows. Hopefully, real servers are not in windows. Try it on linux and share us if the error is the same

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The goal will be to deploy a package onto a Windows based machine. I'm sure the errors won't be present in Linux, but I mean, docker is available on Windows so there must be a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue so I am posting the solution here in case people come across the same issue in the future: git bash changes absolute paths so it is something that should be disabled.

Put this into .bashrc to correct the way paths are handled:

```
# Workaround for Docker for Windows in Git Bash.
docker()
{
        (export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1; "docker.exe" "$@")
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in scenarios where docker run is called from npm scripts, etc. Volume mapping will still break.

See [here](https://github.com/docker-archive/toolbox/issues/673) to continue exploring the issue and seeing possible workarounds

Comment: Powershell works for me too.